# Determine all $2\times 2$ matrices such at $A = A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having issues finding out how to find all of these values. Is there a specific pattern? A formula of some sort?

If $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & a\end{bmatrix}$  then $A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & a\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2=A$, then $A$ is similar to one of the following matrices
$$
       \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right].
$$
This is because every $x$ may be written as $x=(I-A)x+Ax$ and
$$
                A\{(I-A)x\}=0,\;\; A\{ Ax\} = Ax.
$$